# Drag & Drop QTableWidget without changing table

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt4

I am trying to write a small app and want to somehow "catch" the row numbers of when a row is dragged / dropped but with no effect on the table. I have created two files, the first is a MainWindow UI file created in Qt Designer for the basic GUI and the second has the code to layout the QTableWidget with some data.

It works as I want, that is to say it shows a drag and drop movement to the user, but changes nothing when dropped. I have read other posts, but they all seem to be wanting to move the data, so they haven't been of any help with this.

**UiFile.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'UiFile.ui'
#
# Created: Thu Apr  7 21:07:11 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(763, 269)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.tableWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.tableWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.ActionMask)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 763, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 1", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 2", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 3", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 4", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 5", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Column", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 7", None))
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
import UiFile


class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, UiFile.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.my_item_changed_info)

        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R1C1", "R1C2", "R1C3", "R1C4", "R1C5", "R1C6", "R1C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R2C1", "R2C2", "R2C3", "R2C4", "R2C5", "R2C6", "R2C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R3C1", "R3C2", "R3C3", "R3C4", "R3C5", "R3C6", "R3C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R4C1", "R4C2", "R4C3", "R4C4", "R4C5", "R4C6", "R4C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R5C1", "R5C2", "R5C3", "R5C4", "R5C5", "R5C6", "R5C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R6C1", "R6C2", "R6C3", "R6C4", "R6C5", "R6C6", "R6C7")
        self.add_row_to_ml_table("R7C1", "R7C2", "R7C3", "R7C4", "R7C5", "R7C6", "R7C7")

    def add_row_to_ml_table(self, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7):
        rowposition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowposition)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c1))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c2))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c3))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c4))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c5))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c6))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowposition, 6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(c7))

    def my_item_changed_info(self, something):
        if self.tableWidget.currentRow() != -1:
            print("current", self.tableWidget.currentRow(), self.tableWidget.currentColumn())
            print(something.row(), something.column())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Xmms2 Skin', 'Do you want to quit the applictaion?', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So what I need to do is get the information of the row that has been dragged and the row that is being dropped onto.

From what I have read on this I would have to create a sub-Class of the QTableWidget in order to catch the event.

**Can I do that using Qt Designer?** I picked this in the first place according to my programming skills, and this is a small fragment of a much more complex GUI layout.

Comment: I don't think I can edit my question due to new user, but I have found I can use self.tableWidget.__class__.dropEvent = self.testfunc in line 15 of main.py to catch the drop event but cannot work out how to retrieve the row. If I use print(event.source().row() I get TypeError: QTableWidget.row(QTableWidgetItem): not enough arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by adding

```
self.tableWidget.__class__.dropEvent = self.testdropfunc
```

into the home function, and then the testdropfunc looks like this :-

```
def testdropfunc(self, event):
    moved_from = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    moved_to = self.tableWidget.rowAt(event.pos().y())
    print("Drop from " + str(moved_from) + " into row " + str(moved_to))
    event.accept()
```

I do realise that this does not actually move anything as all I wanted was the row information for the item ("dragged from" and "dropped to")